# How to refresh fragment from activity in KOTLIN

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, refresh, onresume

In my kotlin project, I want to refresh fragments from an Actvity. When I finish Activity, it  should refresh the fragment. I was thinking this would be done in onResume. So how to do  refresh current  fragment when I resume an activity? My fragment page contains listviews, hence it should be updated, when i finish activity.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

> Use Swipe to refresh layout

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout)
      swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
           //TODO operation
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt mention - i want source code for kotlin. anyone help pls

Comment: Edited answer check this

Comment: I am using kotlin,  not java. Thanks for your reply.  Is there  any other method available in kotlin?????